# Can I display a table row for a specified period of time

Tags: javascript, css

Hi I am trying to display a row and then want to remove it after a specified amount of time.

I am implementing a timer (using the radio buttons) which takes like 5 seconds to display a page and then they disappear. I want to remove the space where the radio buttons are present.

How Can I remove this space.

I am thinking of adding a timer after which the space collapses but dont know how to achieve the same.

```
                    <TR id="progressBar">
                    <TD ALIGN=RIGHT>
                        <div id="progressRadios">
                            <input type="radio" style="width: 50px;" id="progress1" disabled>
                            <input type="radio" style="width: 50px;" id="progress2" disabled>
                            <input type="radio" style="width: 50px;" id="progress3" disabled>
                            <input type="radio" style="width: 50px;" id="progress4" disabled>
                            <input type="radio" style="width: 50px;" id="progress5" disabled>
                            <BR>
                            <input type="radio" style="width: 50px;" id="progress6" disabled>
                            <input type="radio" style="width: 50px;" id="progress7" disabled>
                            <input type="radio" style="width: 50px;" id="progress8" disabled>
                            <input type="radio" style="width: 50px;" id="progress9" disabled>
                            <input type="radio" style="width: 50px;" id="progress10" disabled>
                        </div>
                    </TD>
                    <TD ALIGN=LEFT>
                        <input type="text" id="progressPct" disabled size=1>
                    </TD>
                </TR>

    function checkProgress() {
        queryJobProgress();
        ++m_iCheckCount;
        var iRadio = Math.round(m_iProgress / 10);
        document.getElementById("progressPct").value = m_iProgress;
        for (var iPrev = 0; iPrev < iRadio; ++iPrev) {
            var oButton = document.getElementById("progress" + iPrev);
            if (oButton != null)
                oButton.checked = false;
        }
        oButton = document.getElementById("progress" + iRadio);
        if (oButton != null)
            oButton.checked = true;
        m_oTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            checkProgress()
        }, 250);

        if (m_iProgress > 100 || m_iCheckCount > 40) {
            resetProgressIndicator();
        }
    }

    function resetProgressIndicator() {
        clearTimeout(m_oTimer);
        document.getElementById("progressPct").value = "";
        document.getElementById("progress10").checked = false;
        m_iProgress = -1;
        m_iCheckCount = -1;

        // Job not running ==>
        //     no need for the progress indicator.
        //     can allow manual adjustment of results.
        document.getElementById("progressBar").style.visibility = "hidden";
        //document.getElementById("semiAutoAdjustments").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
```

Comment: Don't call *setTimeout*, just hide the button immediately.